# Backbone View element not appending the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to append HTML TD tag with list of selected names from another view. It results in an empty div tag. List contains comma separated values.  Can you please explain how to append an attribute to view element?

Following is the code from base view that passes TD as view element.

```
base view
--------

                            var model = new DataNames();
                      var view = new SearchDataView({
                                model:model
                            });
                view.render().showModal({
                    x: event.pageX,
                    y: event.pageY
                            });
                            var dName = new DataNamesView({
                                    el: "#dataName"  // this needs to be populated
                            });
                            dName.render();

subview 1 --- this view gets called from base view

 SearchDataView = Backbone.ModalView.extend(
        {
        name: "SearchDataView",
        model: DataNames,
        templateHtml :  
                "<div id='select'><span>Search name</span>" +
                "<table border='1'>"+
                "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='checkbox' value='test1'></td>"+
                     "<td name='selected'>test1</td>"+
                     "<td></td>"+
                     "<td></td></tr>"+
                     "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='checkbox' value='test2'></td>"+
                     "<td name='selected'>test2</td>"+
                     "<td></td>"+
                     "<td></td></tr>"+

"</table><button id='select'>Select</button></div>", 


                initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll( this, "render");
                                this.template = _.template( this.templateHtml);
                        },
        events: {
                "click #select": "select"
                        },
                select: function(){
                                 var allVals = [];
                                 $('#select :checked').each(function() {
                                   allVals.push($(this).val());
                                 });
                                 alert(allVals);
                                 this.model.set("name",allVals);
                                 var dName = new DataNamesView({selectedList: allVals});
                                 dName.render();
                                 this.hideModal();
                              },        
        render: function(){
                            $(this.el).html(this.templateHtml); 
                            return this;
            }
    });


subview 2
----------  

        DataNamesView = Backbone.ModalView.extend(
        {
        name: "DataNamesView",

                initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll( this, "render");
                            var selectedList = this.options.selectedList;
                        },
        events: {

                        },
                render: function(name){
                                alert("selected from names view"+this.options.selectedList);

                                this.el.innerHTML = "testing";// this works fine
                            // $(this.el).html(this.options.selectedList); //does not work 
                            //this.el.innerHTML = this.options.selectedList;//does not work
                            //this.$el.append(this.options.selectedList); //does not work
                            return this;
                           }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code for the view.

Comment: //var model = new Datasource();
var model = new DatasourceNames();
var view = new SearchDatasourceView({
                    model:model
});
view.render().showModal({
   x: event.pageX,
   y: event.pageY
               });
           var dsName = new DatasourceNamesView({
                      el: "#datasourceName"
                 });               dsName.render();

Comment: Please update your original question to include the code.  That way the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: Please discard previous post. following code is from base dialog which passes TD as view element to another dialog                                                                var model = new DataNames();                                      var view = new SearchDataView({
                      model:model
              });
view.render().showModal({
 x: event.pageX,
 y: event.pageY
        });
var dsName = new DataNamesView({
              el: "#dataName"
});
dsName.render();

Comment: I do not understand your code. How are you extending backbone.view object? Where are you passing selectedList to the view? Please modify your original question to include full code for your view.

Comment: Updated my question. PLease take a look.